# Geometry - Simple Subdivision Surface Node doesn't see

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm making it after Late as usual's(https://twitter.com/lateasusual_/status/1364305410526707713/photo/1) node, but the Simple Subdivision Surface node does not exist in the geometry node. There is just a Subdivide node, but according to the manual description, it seems to be a completely different node, so it is ambiguous to use it.
In addition, the configuration of the Attribute Proxy node seems to be different from the node in the tutorial.
What should I do?

(I'm using a translator, so please understand if the sentence is a bit awkward.)
[image]

Comment: The geometry nodes have gone through a lot of changes in the last few Blender updates, so tutorials are bound to be out of date unless they're very recent.

Comment: Ok, but the tutorial's blender version is 2.93.0, and my blender version is 2.93.1. Also I tested that on blender 2.93.0, but the problem was the same.
Can there be a difference in functions even if the versions are the same?

Comment: I wouldn't think the same version could have different functions. That's weird. I have no idea, then.